# Check for duplicate values in Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

**Is there a way in pandas to check if a dataframe column has duplicate values, without actually dropping rows?** I have a function that will remove duplicate rows, however, I only want it to run if there are actually duplicates in a specific column.

Currently I compare the number of unique values in the column to the number of rows: if there are less unique values than rows then there are duplicates and the code runs.

```
 if len(df['Student'].unique()) < len(df.index):
    # Code to remove duplicates based on Date column runs
```

Is there an easier or more efficient way to check if duplicate values exist in a specific column, using pandas?

Some of the sample data I am working with (only two columns shown). If duplicates are found then another function identifies which row to keep (row with oldest date):

```
    Student Date
0   Joe     December 2017
1   James   January 2018
2   Bob     April 2018
3   Joe     December 2017
4   Jack    February 2018
5   Jack    March 2018
```

Comment: sort your df  by date then `df.drop_duplicates('student')`

Comment: @Wen Yes this, but maybe convert to datetime and sort after. Quick check would be: `any(df['Student'].duplicated())`

Comment: A couple of misunderstandings: a) it's never necessary to check `len(df[col].unique())`, pandas has `df[col].nunique()` b) but anyway you don't even need that either, **you're just looking for [`df[col].duplicated(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)**

Answer (score 123, accepted):

### Main question

> Is there a duplicate value in a column, **True**/**False**?

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Student ║ Date          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Joe     ║ December 2017 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Bob     ║ April 2018    ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Joe     ║ December 2018 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Assuming above dataframe (**df**), we could do a quick check if duplicated in the `Student` col by:

```
boolean = not df["Student"].is_unique      # True (credit to @Carsten)
boolean = df['Student'].duplicated().any() # True
```

---

### Further reading and references

Above we are using one of the Pandas Series methods. The pandas DataFrame has several useful [methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), two of which are:

1. [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates)(self[, subset, keep, inplace]) - *Return DataFrame with duplicate rows removed, optionally only considering certain columns.*
2. [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated)(self[, subset, keep]) - *Return boolean Series denoting duplicate rows, optionally only considering certain columns.*

These methods can be applied on the DataFrame as a whole, and not just a Serie (column) as above. The equivalent would be:

```
boolean = df.duplicated(subset=['Student']).any() # True
# We were expecting True, as Joe can be seen twice.
```

However, if we are interested in the whole frame we could go ahead and do:

```
boolean = df.duplicated().any() # False
boolean = df.duplicated(subset=['Student','Date']).any() # False
# We were expecting False here - no duplicates row-wise 
# ie. Joe Dec 2017, Joe Dec 2018
```

And a final useful tip. By using the `keep` paramater we can normally skip a few rows directly accessing what we need:

> keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’

- first : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.
- last : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.
- False : Drop all duplicates.

---

### Example to play around with

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''\
Student,Date
Joe,December 2017
Bob,April 2018
Joe,December 2018'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')

# Approach 1: Simple True/False
boolean = df.duplicated(subset=['Student']).any()
print(boolean, end='\n\n') # True

# Approach 2: First store boolean array, check then remove
duplicate_in_student = df.duplicated(subset=['Student'])
if duplicate_in_student.any():
    print(df.loc[~duplicate_in_student], end='\n\n')

# Approach 3: Use drop_duplicates method
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Student'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Returns

```
True

  Student           Date
0     Joe  December 2017
1     Bob     April 2018

  Student           Date
0     Joe  December 2017
1     Bob     April 2018
```

Comment: Thanks, any(df['Student'].duplicated()) was what I was after.

Comment: Incidentally, I wasn't able to get the date conversion to work (my existing function did work though). I got the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date' for the line df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

Comment: @JeffMitchell `df.Date` equals `df['Date']`. It is case-sensitive. Are you sure your columns is called Date? Could try `df['Date']` too

Answer (score 18):

You can use `is_unique`:

```
df['Student'].is_unique

# equals true in case of no duplicates
```

Older pandas versions required:

```
pd.Series(df['Student']).is_unique
```

Comment: You just need to do `df['Student'].is_unique`. `df['Student']` is already a Pandas series

Comment: True, older pandas versions however struggled with that. Edited the answer now

Answer (score 9):

If you want to know how many duplicates & what they are use:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['ColumnName'], aggfunc='size')

df.pivot_table(index=['ColumnName1',.., 'ColumnNameN'], aggfunc='size')
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [**`DataFrame.duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [**`Series.duplicated`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), Pandas also has a [**`DataFrame.any`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [**`Series.any`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv")
```

With Python ≥3.8, check for duplicates and access some duplicate rows:

```py
if (duplicated := df.duplicated(keep=False)).any():
    some_duplicates = df[duplicated].sort_values(by=df.columns.to_list()).head()
    print(f"Dataframe has one or more duplicated rows, for example:\n{some_duplicates}")
```