# How can I merge/join multiple columns from two dataframes, depending on a matching pattern

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to merge two dataframes based on similar patterns in the chromosome column. I made various attempts with R & BASH such as with "data.table" "tidyverse", & merge(). Could someone help me by providing alternative solutions in R, BASH, Python, Perl, etc. for solving this solution? I would like to merge based on the chromosome information and retain both counts/RXNs.

NOTE: These two DFs are not aligned and I am also curious what happens if some values are missing.

Thanks and Cheers:

DF1:

```
Chromosome;RXN;ID
1009250;q9hxn4;NA
1010820;p16256;NA
31783;p16588;"PNTOt4;PNTOt4pp"
203;3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN;"DHQTi;DQDH"
```

DF2:

```
Chromosome;Count1;Count2;Count3;Count4;Count5
203;1;31;1;0;0;0
1010820;152;7;0;11;4
1009250;5;0;0;17;0
31783;1;0;0;0;0;0
```

Expected Result:

```
Chromosome;RXN;Count1;Count2;Count3;Count4;Count5
1009250;q9hxn4;5;0;0;17;0
1010820;p16256;152;7;0;11;4
31783;p16588;1;0;0;0;0
203;3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN;1;31;1;0;0;0
```

Comment: so `Chromosome1` in `df1` should match `Chromosome2` in `df2`?

Comment: ```Chromosome1``` & ```Chromosome2``` in your example have no match. Do you want to just join the two tables?

Comment: Can you articulate more what "a matching pattern that is similar" means for your use case? It sounds subjective, and programming solutions work best with objective definitions.

Comment: It seems that the expected result here relies on different DF2 data that what you have provided, which will make it impossible for us to test any potential solution. Can you please fix that?

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback so far. I adjusted both datasets and clarified the question. I would like to match the 'Chromosome' column head found in both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bash was mentioned in the text body, I offer you an awk solution. The dataframes are in files `df1` and `df2`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"         # input and output field delimiters
}
NR==FNR {              # process df1
    a[$1]=$2           # hash to an array, 1st is the key, 2nd the value
    next               # process next record
}
{                      # process df2
    $2=(a[$1] OFS $2)  # prepend RXN field to 2nd field of df2
}1' df1 df2            # 1 is output command, mind the file order
```

The 2 last lines could be written perhaps more clearly:

```
...
{
    print $1,a[$1],$2,$3,$4,$5,$6
}' df1 df2
```

Output:

```
Chromosome;RXN;Count1;Count2;Count3;Count4;Count5
203;3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN;1;31;1;0;0;0
1010820;p16256;152;7;0;11;4
1009250;q9hxn4;5;0;0;17;0
31783;p16588;1;0;0;0;0;0
```

Output will be in the order of `df2`. Chromosome present in `df1` but not in `df2` will not be included. Chromosome in `df2` but not in `df1` will be output from `df2` with empty RXN field. Also, if there are duplicate chromosomes in `df1`, the last one is used. This can be fixed if it is an issue.

Comment: This solution is very elegant and clean, thank you for suggesting this solution. I spent days trying to use AWK, but could not figure it out. You are truly a BASH Wizard :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, this should do it in Python. I've made the Chromosome column into the index of each DataFrame.

```
from io import StringIO

txt1 = '''Chromosome;RXN;ID
1009250;q9hxn4;NA
1010820;p16256;NA
31783;p16588;"PNTOt4;PNTOt4pp"
203;3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN;"DHQTi;DQDH"'''

txt2 = """Chromosome;Count1;Count2;Count3;Count4;Count5;Count6
203;1;31;1;0;0;0
1010820;152;7;0;11;4
1009250;5;0;0;17;0
31783;1;0;0;0;0;0"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(txt1),
    sep=';',
    index_col=0,
    header=0
)

df2 = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(txt2),
    sep=';',
    index_col=0,
    header=0
)
```

```
DF1:
                                         RXN               ID
Chromosome
1009250                               q9hxn4              NaN
1010820                               p16256              NaN
31783                                 p16588  PNTOt4;PNTOt4pp
203         3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN       DHQTi;DQDH

DF2:
            Count1  Count2  Count3  Count4  Count5  Count6
Chromosome
203              1      31       1       0       0     0.0
1010820        152       7       0      11       4     NaN
1009250          5       0       0      17       0     NaN
31783            1       0       0       0       0     0.0
```

```
result = pd.concat(
    [df1.sort_index(), df2.sort_index()],
    axis=1
)
print(result)
```

```
                                         RXN               ID  Count1  Count2  Count3  Count4  Count5  Count6
Chromosome
203         3-DEHYDROQUINATE-DEHYDRATASE-RXN       DHQTi;DQDH       1      31       1       0       0     0.0
31783                                 p16588  PNTOt4;PNTOt4pp       1       0       0       0       0     0.0
1009250                               q9hxn4              NaN       5       0       0      17       0     NaN
1010820                               p16256              NaN     152       7       0      11       4     NaN
```

The concat command also handles mismatched indices by simply filling in NaN values for columns in e.g. df1 if df2 doesn't have have the same index, and vice versa.

Comment: Hey @Nick, that was very useful as a start for me. What does it mean that you made the 'Chromosome' column into an index of each DF? How did you do it in this case?

I tried: 
`df1.set_index('Chromosome',inplace=True) `
But it did not provide the results that I expected. I still have two unique columns with 'Chromosome'. Thanks again !

Comment: Thank you. I've now added the code where I load the data and set the Chromosome column as the index. I've also added a column 'Count6', since it seemed to be missing to match with the number of columns present.

Comment: Thank you for specifying how to set a column as an index However, I am using two large files, not strings. I am continuing to hit the error:

`raise InvalidIndexError(
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

I thought the issue would be that I have duplicates in the row that was indexed, but it has not changed much

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_csv('DF1.csv', sep=';',index_col=0,header=0)
print (df1)
df1.index
df2 = pd.read_csv ('DF1.csv', sep=';',index_col=0,header=0)
print (df2)
df2.index

result = pd.concat(
    [df1.sort_index(), df2.sort_index()],
    axis=1)

#Error arises here

print(result)
result.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)`

Comment: It sounds like there are duplicate Chromosome entries. I'd suggest checking with one of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242968/check-for-duplicate-values-in-pandas-dataframe-column

Comment: Otherwise, can you share the data files? The error is you get is hard to troubleshoot without all the data.

Comment: Thanks Nick, the issue was with the duplications which I cleared up today. Now I am trying to figure out what the 'Chromosome' columns from both files are not matching with the remaining row data.